# Node Twitter API only writing one result in excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, twitter, bots

I have followed a tutorial and expanded on it to make this twitter bot. It takes the latest 100 tweets from the given twitter account and gives me the dates they were posted when I run the program in terminal. This bit works perfectly.

The 3 lines at the bottom are used to write the data to a spreadsheet although it only gives me one result. I'm wanting to know if there's anything I have done wrong or if there is anything I can add that will give me all the results in the spreadsheet?

**This is the code I have written**

```
//API
var Twit = require('twit');

// Getting the API keys from the config file.
var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

//getting 5 tweets from the username entered in the top username.
//can get up to 3200 tweets
var params = {
  screen_name: 'mascott10',
  count: 100
}

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, gotData);

//function to be triggered when the data is collected.
function gotData(err, data, response) {
  var tweets = data;
  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
  console.log(tweets[i].created_at);
var date_posted =  tweets[i].created_at.toString();
  }

  //console.log(data);

  //write to file
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile("/Users/mikey/Desktop/node/test.xls", date_posted);
};
```

**This is some of the results in terminal**

[terminal view of bot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6HWg.png)

**This is the result in the spreadsheet**

[spreadsheet result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtxdP.png)

Comment: well `var date_posted =  tweets[i].created_at.toString();` holds the last value

Answer (score 0):

Your code is over-writing `date_posted` on each iteration of the `for` loop.  Define your `date_posted` variable outside of the loop:

`var date_posted;`

And then inside of the loop concatenate each successive date:

`date_posted +=  tweets[i].created_at.toString();`